# How to pick the rows which contains all the keywords?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 csv files as below :

### File-1

```
procedure   code
anand database  321-87
shiva network   321-123
jana audit  321-56
kalai recruitment   321-10
```

in file-1, each word in a row is a key word.

### File-2

```
s.no    procedure
1   kalai has a recruitment group
2   shiva is the network person in my office
3   he is the auditor in my office
4   anand is the database here
5   i bought a new phone this week
6   jana is working in the audit team
```

in the above scenario, i need to pick the row in file-2 which contains all the key words of each row in file-1. suppose for example, row-1 in file-1 contains 2 key words 'anand' & 'database'. i need to select the row in file-2 which contains both the keywords 'anand' & 'database'.

can anyone help me out in this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: s i tried with normal looping and by doing word_tokenize...but i didn't get solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `df` is relatively small, you could use `str.contains`. First, build a pattern from `df`.

```
df

           procedure     code
0     anand database   321-87
1      shiva network  321-123
2         jana audit   321-56
3  kalai recruitment   321-10

p = df.procedure.str.split().str.join('.*?').str.cat(sep='|')

p
'anand.*?database|shiva.*?network|jana.*?audit|kalai.*?recruitment'
```

Now, pass it to `str.contains` on `df2.procedure`.

```
df2[df2.procedure.str.contains(p)]

   s.no                                 procedure
0     1             kalai has a recruitment group
1     2  shiva is the network person in my office
3     4                anand is the database here
5     6         jana is working in the audit team
```

Comment: Cool pattern, I thought of joining but you already posted an answer.

Comment: @Dark I believe there are more solutions using `findall` and `extract`. I leave them to you, feel free to answer.

Comment: @coldspeed was wanting to try flash text on pandas. I added a solution

Comment: hi...its working...thanks a lot. i need to add the "code" field of df1 (file-1) with the picked rows of df2 (file-2). how to do with this ?

Comment: hi while running the 2nd line which is "v" i am getting the following error:-  "error: bad character range K-B"

Comment: @Prabu What you did was a little unfair. The protocol in this case is to open a new question if you have a followup. Rather than cite protocol, I decided to help you with your second question. My initial answer addresses your first question, so I find it a little unfair that you accepted the other answer just because I couldn't solve your extension problem.

Comment: @Prabu Yes, this answer is what you asked for right?  And besides this was the first answer. Please accept this one.  Thats why we always ask to show ur effort in solving the problem which gives us the indication of what exactly is that you want. Post another question if you have a follow up

Comment: @Prabu Okay, now please open a new question. Hopefully someone else will be more willing to help you with your follow up query.

Comment: @COLDSPEED...i was little confused. i didnt purposely did this. sorry.

Comment: @coldspeed: hi kindly help me in the above problem frnd. as i mentioned yesterday i am getting  error. i cant able to resolve it.

Comment: @Prabu That's not how this site works. If you have another problem, please open a new question. Each post is meant for a separate, atomic query.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: hi i have raised a new question for the above. can u kindly help me in this now?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution than regex is flashtext, this will be faster if you have more number of keywords i.e

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor
keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor()
keyword_processor.add_keywords_from_list(df['procedure'].str.split().sum())

df2[df2['procedure'].apply(keyword_processor.extract_keywords).str.len()>1]

    s.no                                procedure
0     1             kalai has a recruitment group
1     2  shiva is the network person in my office
3     4                anand is the database here
5     6         jana is working in the audit team
```

To know more about this library and its speed you can check here

Further Reading :

1. [Docs](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext)
2. [Regex was taking 5 days to run. So I built a tool that did it in 15 minutes.](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/regex-was-taking-5-days-flashtext-does-it-in-15-minutes-55f04411025f)

There is a need for easy interface via pandas, lets wait till its done.

Comment: Upvoted, but someone should make a variant for this API that doesn't need an `apply`. I believe it has to start with the code.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes, so many text processing is done via pandas an api to support this library would be so awesome

Comment: hi...i tried this....it was working. but i need to add concern "code" field of file-1 for the output picked.